# error when using expandafter for databib command in indexing command in foreach loop

Tags: indexing, expansion, datatool, pgffor

I'm trying to create an author index using the databib package (datatool) bundle. I can loop over the entries in a BibTeX database and for each entry, loop over the authors using the `\foreach` command from the pgffor package. I then would like to add the author to the index, but this fails.

The following minimal example illustrates the issue:

```
\begin{filecontents}{data.bib}
@inproceedings{test,
  Author = {Author One and Auteur Twee},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{databib,pgffor}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
  \makeindex[name=test]

\newcommand*{\invertfourargs}[4]{#4 #3 #2 #1}

\begin{document}
  \invertfourargs{a}{b}{c}{d}

  ***

  \def\multiplefourargs{{c}{d}{e}{f},{g}{h}{i}{j}}
  \foreach \fourargs in \multiplefourargs {%
    \expandafter\invertfourargs\fourargs+}
  \foreach \fourargs in \multiplefourargs {%
    \index[test]{\expandafter\invertfourargs\fourargs}}

  ***

  % GET DATA OUT OF BIBFILE INTO DB
  \nocite{*}
  \DTLloadbbl{data}{data.bib}

  \DTLforeachbibentry*{data}{
    \DTLbibfieldlet{\Authors}{Author}
    \foreach \Author in \Authors {%
      \expandafter\DTLformatauthor\Author+}
%     \foreach \Author in \Authors {% THIS DOES NOT WORK
%       \index[test]{\expandafter\DTLformatauthor\Author}}
  }

  \printindex[test]
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
Runaway definition?
->\write \test@idxfile {\indexentry{\let \global \advance \dtlforeachlevel \ETC
.
! File ended while scanning definition of \reserved@a.
<inserted text> 
                }
```

What should I do to fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not to expand the `\Author` (\index will do it anyway) but to prevent the expansion of `\DTLformatauthor` when the index is written. So use

```
 \index[test]{\protect\DTLformatauthor\Author}}
```

Comment: What is then the essential difference between `\DTLformatauthor` and `\invertfourargs`?

Comment: The invertfourargs is expandable and can be executed while writing the .ind. Look in test.ind to see the differences.